# session with spring and iframe

Tags: spring, jsp, iframe

I work with spring and jsp ( which include iframe)

I have problem with session

I have the login page ( index.jsp) and I have other page ( menu.jsp) which include iframe

I want when the session is expired to redirect from menu.jsp  to  index.jsp

this is my index.jsp :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> -->
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>



<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>index</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Test/theme/login.css">
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link href="default_ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>


<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="page">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="content_space">

                <form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />" method="POST">    

                    <c:if test="${param.error == 1}">
                        <h3 style="font-size:20; color:#FF1C19;">error.</h3>
                    </c:if>
            <table dir="ltr">
                <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td width="100%">
                    <table align="left" width="100%" dir="ltr" style="padding-top: 35px;">


                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td width="10"></td>
                            <td><input name="j_username" type="text" value=""></td>
                            <td width="10"></td>
                            <td style="color: #000000" align="right">username</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="100%">

                    <span id="_58_passwordCapsLockSpan" style="display: none;">Caps Lock is on.</span><table align="left" dir="ltr" width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td width="10"></td>
                            <td><input name="j_password" type="password" value=""></td>
                            <td width="10"></td>
                            <td style="color: #000000" align="right">login</td>
                        </tr>


                    </tbody></table>
                     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <table align="left" dir="ltr" style="padding-left: 15px;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="signinAR" value=""></td>
                            <td width="10"></td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody></table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my menu.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@page import="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails"%>
<%@page import="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder"%>
 <% 
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();



Boolean enbaleSMenu = false;




if(request.isUserInRole("ADMIN")){
    enbaleSMenu=true;
} 






Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String username = "";

    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {

          username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();

    } else {

         username = principal.toString();

    }
    if(username.equals("anonymousUser")){
        response.sendRedirect("/Test/index.htm");
        parent.reLoadPage();
    }

 %>




<html>
<head>
  <title>menu</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Test/theme/default.css">



     <script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/extjs/jquery-latest.min.js'/>"></script>    
     <script type="text/javascript"
    src="<c:url value='/extjs/main.js'/>"></script> 
         <script>

 function loadIframe(iframeName, url) {
   var $iframe = $('#' + iframeName);
   if ( $iframe.length ) {
       $iframe.attr('src',url);   
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
        function reLoadPage(){
            location.replace("/Test/index.htm");
            location.reload();

        }
          // hidding menu
            var hiddenSMenu=<%=enbaleSMenu%>;   


function showMenu()

{



        if(hiddenSMenu)
            {

               document.getElementById("idSmenu").children[2].style.display="none";

                   loadIframe('cmpframe', '/Test/administration/Validation.htm');  


            }
        else
            {

               document.getElementById("idSmenu").children[0].style.display="none";
               document.getElementById("idSmenu").children[1].style.display="none"; 


             loadIframe('cmpframe', '/Test/citizen/Request.htm');  


            }


}



</script> 


 <style type="text/css">
    label.myBold
    {
       font-weight: bold;
       text-decoration: none;
        color: red;
    }

    .my-fieldset {
      background: #F1F3FB,
      border: 1px solid red
    }
    .my-fieldset .x-fieldset-header {
      color: red
    }





</style>  


</head>
<body dir="rtl" onload="showMenu()" >
        <script>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%> 



</script>


        <a href="<c:url value="../j_spring_security_logout" />" > ????</a>

      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo_left">
                <p>
                    <img src="/Test/theme/images/Taif_logo.png">
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="logo">
                <h1><a href="./index.html"><img src="/Test/theme/images/MIS_logo.png"></a></h1>
            </div>


        </div>

<div id="page">
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
 <li style="display: none;><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><span><spring:message code="label.titleProjet"/></span></a>
      <ul id="idSmenu">
        <li class="current"><a href="/Test/administration/Info.htm" target="myframe"><spring:message code="label.consult"/></a></li>

        <li class="current"><a href="/Test/administration/Validation.htm" target="myframe"><spring:message code="label.validate"/></a></li>

         <li class="current"><a href="/Test/citizen/Request.htm" target="myframe"><spring:message code="label.Request"/></a></li>


      </ul>
        </li>

   </li>



</ul>
</div>
<div id = "divFrame" > 
 <iframe id="cmpframe" name="myframe" width="84%" height="100%" >

</iframe></div>

        </div>

    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

this is the code whcih should redirect from menu.jsp to index.jsp  when the session is expired :

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String username = "";

    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {

          username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();

    } else {

         username = principal.toString();

    }
    if(username.equals("anonymousUser")){
        response.sendRedirect("/Test/index.htm");
        parent.reLoadPage();
    }
```

but with this code I have also the same problem

Updated :

this is my error when I test this code :

```
parent cannot be resolved
39:     }
40:     if(username.equals("anonymousUser")){
41:         response.sendRedirect("/Test/index.htm");
42:         parent.reLoadPage();
43:     }
44: 
45:
```

I didn't know how can I declare **parent**

Comment: what problem do you face in this

Comment: I need help  to solve this problem, nobody has idea in this problem of session related to spring and iframe